# css :disabled::after not working

Tags: css

Can't seem to get the following selector working.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
   html body div#main_container form#account_info input[type=text]:disabled::after, input[type=email]:disabled::after {
     content: "dfjnsfnj";
     position: absolute; float: none; clear: both; display: block;
     top: 0; left: 0;
     width: 100px; height: 100px; margin: 0; padding: 0;

     font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif; font-weight: 600; font-size: 25px; line-height: 25px; text-align: left;
     letter-spacing: -3px;
     color: #3d5a71;
     background-color: red;
   }
```

Comment: That really is a masterfully crafted wrong CSS selector. One part is far too specific, the other is overly generic. And to answer the question: an `input` is a self-closing element that cannot contain child elements, thus no pseudo elements either.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Care to explain? Works fine without the `:disabled` selector. But doesn't work with it...

Comment: @Harry that linked duplicate is actually incredibly wrong. It's simply forbidden by HTML specs to apply pseudoelements to childless elements.

Comment: I see it's sort of working in Chrome indeed, but that's a bug for sure. [Check this link](http://www.scottohara.me/article/pseudo-element-input.html).

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes I reopened. Pseudo elements can't be applied to `input` elements, though. That's part of the reason why the OP's code isn't working.. What's a better duplicate?

Comment: @JoshCrozier typed a better answer, can link future duplicates here  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it can't be applied onto `input` elements.

Added it to the `label` instead. Works now :)!

```
html body div#main_container form#account_info input:disabled[type=text] + label:after, 
html body div#main_container form#account_info input:disabled[type=email] + label:after {}
```

Comment: You should actually use `+` here instead of `~`, made the same booboo in my example. The first one will correctly allow multiple checkboxes with different definitions. And please, strip all unneeded elements from your selectors - `#account_info input[type=text]:disabled ~ label::after` is just as specific as what you have now.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Like that above^?

Comment: Yep, and now for brevity hehe.

Answer (score 5):

While I verified that the construct does work somewhat in current Chrome stable, this seems an unfortunate by-effect of generic parsing.

`input` is [specified in the HTML5 standards](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element) as having an **"Empty"** content model, like other self-closing elements such as `<br>` and `<img>`. All of them are therefore not permitted, *in any situation*, to have child elements. Including pseudo-elements.

Your problem is easily solved by including some extra markup, which would insert the generated content in a more plausible location in the doctree than as the child element of a checkbox. The following example works fine and is semantically correct:

```css
input:disabled[type=checkbox] + label:after {
  content:' testing this CSS';
}
```

```html
<input disabled type="checkbox">
<label>Checkbox for</label>
```